# How to turn off this kind of FPS counter overlay?

Tags: linux, nvidia-graphics-card, fps

I turned it on by pressing some keyboard shortcut by mistake. What is the way to turn it off?

[image: Screenshot of the FPS counter I accidentally enabled.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're seeing doesn't belong to Chrome, but rather is from OpenGL settings from Nvidia X server settings.

Open up Nvidia X server settings by running the command:

```
nvidia-settings
```

On the left side bar under `X Screen __` (where `__` is most likely `0`), click `OpenGL Settings`.

Uncheck the `Enable Graphics API Visual Indicator` under `Miscellaneous`.